# how to backup a django db

Tags: django, database-backups, database-restore

I have a Django application that uses a Postgres database.  I need to be able to backup and restore the db, both to ensure no data is lost and to be able to copy data from the production server to the development server during testing.

There seem to be a few different ways to do this:

1. Just interact with the db directly.  So, for Postgres I might write a script using `pg_dumpall` and `psql`.
2. Use the `sqlclear`/`sqlall` commands that come with Django.
3. Use the `dumpdata`/`loaddata` commands that come with Django.  So create new fixtures from the db you want to backup and then load them into the db you want to restore.
4. Use a Django plugin like [django-dbbackup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dbbackup).

I really don't understand the pros/cons of these different techniques.

Just off the top of my head: Option 1 is database-specific and option 3 seems more suited to setting up initial data.  But I'm still not sure what advantages option 4 has over option 2.

Comment: why dont you just create a copy of the entire database ? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html#BACKUP-DUMP

Comment: does django-dbbackup even work? I clearly see code there, that hasn't got a chance to work: https://bitbucket.org/mjs7231/django-dbbackup/src/4702d2cf91987fd8a4122b95afca5d42cd477d00/dbbackup/storage/s3_storage.py?at=default#cl-56

Comment: @karthikr - That would work but the commands are specific to Postgres; if the underlying db changes, I would have to rewrite the script.

Comment: @vartec - I haven't fully tested it yet.  The bit of code you were looking at saves to Amazon S3, I was just going to save to a local file.

Comment: Fair enough, I'd be cautious of code containing such obvious error thought. Especially for tasks as important, as taking backups.

Comment: You mention you ended up writing your own scripts - how do they compare to django-dbbackup? and care to share?

Comment: @Chozabu - The script that I wrote can be found here: http://pastebin.com/3afcrHqe .  It assumes a standard Django "settings.py" w/ all the database info.

Comment: @trubliphone Fantastic! seems rather sensible - the backup runs fine, after filling in the couple of lines that need tailoring to my project, but what about restoring?

Comment: @Chozabu - The restore is very similar: http://pastebin.com/2hbkwsp0 .

Comment: @trubliphone Looks good! Thanks again, upvotes all over :) I'll do some heavy testing on these (django-db backup was giving some UTF-8 related errors on restore) - I was just starting on my own basic bash scripts for this, but your python scripts look much better!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For regular backups I'd go for option 1, using PostgreSQL's own native tool, as it is probably the most efficient.

I would argue that option 2 is primarily concerned with creating the tables and loading initial data so is not suitable for backups.

Option 3 can be used for backups and would be particularly useful if you needed to migrate to a different database platform since the data is dumped in a non-SQL form, i.e. JSON understood by Django.

Option 4 the plugin appears to be using db's own backup tools (as per option 1) but additionally provides help to push your backups into cloud storage in Amazon S3 or Dropbox

Comment: I wound up writing my own Python scripts to backup/restore the database.  They read from the Django settings module to figure out what type of db it is.  Currently, it only supports postgres.  But there are hooks for other formats.

Comment: @trubliphone can you upload it to Git or somewhere and provide the script. ?

Comment: @ajinzrathod - I haven't used this code in _years_.  But I you can find links to my old scripts in the comments above:  https://pastebin.com/3afcrHqe and http://pastebin.com/2hbkwsp0.  (Note that these are 5+ years old; Django may have moved on in the meantime.)

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not see the year. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 41):

The problem with options 1-3 are that media files (anything uploaded through [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#filefield)) are **not included** in the backup. It is possible to separately backup the directory containing the media files. However, because Django doesn't remove files when they are no longer referenced by a `FileField`, you will inevitably end up with files in the backup that don't need to be there.

That's why I would go with option #4. In particular, I recommend [django-archive](http://django-archive.readthedocs.org/)<sup>*</sup>. Some of its features include:

- Dumps the contents of all important models (by default `ContentType`, `Permission`, and `Session` are excluded since they are populated by `manage.py migrate`) and lets you choose additional models to exclude.
- Includes media files referenced by `FileField` and `ImageField` fields. Note that *only* the files referenced by rows in the database are included; files left over by deleted rows are ignored.
- Produces a single archive containing both the database backup and media files.
- Provides options for customizing the location where archives should be stored, the filename format, and archive type (`gz` and `bz2`).

Installation is as simple as adding `django_archive` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and setting options in `settings.py` if needed. Once installed, you can immediately create an archive of your entire database (including media files) by running:

```
./manage.py archive
```

---

<sup>* **Disclaimer:** I am the author of the package</sup>

Comment: That is a good point. For my particular project, I didn't have to worry about media files.  But other users may find your package useful.

Comment: Is there a way to call it programmatically from the Django application, rather than `manage.py`?

Comment: Also, I get a broken archive on Windows Python 3.7 .

Comment: Does references to content types are restored after migrate?

Comment: @SergeRogatch The issue causing that has been fixed in a subsequent release.

Comment: @SergeRogatch to call it programmatically you could use call_command : from django.core.management import call_command

Comment: The package was not interesting