# Django import errors for app csvimport

Tags: django

I really don't know where to start with this error message so wondering if anyone's seen similar before? The weird thing is that my CSV import itself actually works fine, but I am a tad concerned by the error messages:

```
 Applying csvimport.0002_test_models...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "csvtests_country"
LINE 1: ...CONSTRAINT "csvtests_item_country_id_5f8b06b9_fk_"csvtests_c...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 93, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/mikey/.virtualenvs/fanta/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "csvtests_country"
LINE 1: ...CONSTRAINT "csvtests_item_country_id_5f8b06b9_fk_"csvtests_c...
                                                             ^
```

I can't even tell from the error message what potential .py files that may be the source. My models.py seems fine, settings seems fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to delete all .pyc files `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete`.

Comment: Paste the code from `0002_test_models` migrations file.

Comment: There is no 0002_test_models file I am afraid

Comment: I have [developed a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41732280/2996101) which backups the database, deletes all migrations, deletes the database, recreates everything and installs the data from the backup. It is not considered "production savvy" but I got rid of most of this kind of problems.

Comment: In addition to the migration, it'd be useful to be able to see your models.py