# Django - migrating only new migrations after loading dump

Tags: django, django-migrations

The migration process of my test suite got very long in my project,
so I created a **pg_dump** which I load to my DB each time I run my unit tests.

Now the **pg_dump** was created manually, (which later I tend to integrate into a CI system)
However now, I have some other migrations I created after the dump (and I don't want to create a new dump) and I need to run migrations.

My question:
How do I make django migrate **only** the new migrations?
When running
`python manage.py migrate`
it migrates **everything**, it migrates all the migrations as if the dump was not loaded

I searched for this topic online but found addressing this specific problem.
The closest thing I found was this post which wasn't very helpful for me
[Django backup strategy with dumpdata and migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822002/django-backup-strategy-with-dumpdata-and-migrations)

**EDIT**:
This happened because I didn't load the dump the test database, after fixing that it worked,

Comment: What do you mean by "everything"?  If you load the **pg_dump** before you run `manage.py migrate`, django will only apply new migrations.

Comment: it migrates all the migrations as if the dump was not loaded

Comment: Does your **pg_dump** include the `django_migrations` table?

Comment: It then isn't loaded otherwise the first migration will fail already. Are you sure you're loading your dump into the *test* database?

Comment: @Melvyn you are correct,
I didn't load the dump to the test database
thanks!